# Ruby-On-Rails How to allow only current user to edit and delete posts they have created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making a blog application and when the user is viewing the post index view I want them to only edit and delete posts they have created. I am getting the following error:

undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass

views/posts/index.html

```
    <td><% if current_user.id == @post.user_id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        <% end %>
```

The above is my if statement that allows user to only edit and delete posts they have created.

create method in post_controller:

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        form

at.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: if you are following convention, you most probably don't have an `@post` instance variable in the index action.  You have `@posts` and then you loop through it using `each`, ie `@posts.each do |post|`.  So change `@post` to `post` in the index view and see if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do a before action filter for the edit, update and destroy action:

```
before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

def correct_user
    @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:id])  // find the post
    unless current_user?(@post.user)
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    end
  end
```

`current_user?(@post.user)` this checks if the current_user and the @post.user that you defined when you create a new post are the same.

In my sessionHelper I have to methods for defining the current user:

```
  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def current_user
    if(user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    end
  end
```

In your post view you have to add conditional code to render the edit and delete links only if the user is the correct one:

```
<% if current_user?(post.user) %>
          <%= link_to "Edit", edit_micropost_path(micropost) %>
          <%= link_to "Delete", micropost, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Do you want to delete this post ?"}%>
          <% end %>
```

Comment: When you say post view do you mean index view?

Comment: I added your code to my posts index view and then i got this error

undefined method `current_user?' for #<#<Class:0xa3f40b8>:0x62c3688>

Comment: You didn't add the code from the SessionHelper. Do you login users and do you set the current_user ?

Comment: Yes, the index view.

Answer (score 1):

you want to make sure that the if statement is out side of the TD tag

```
    <% if current_user && current_user.id == @post.user_id %>
      <td></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    <% end %>



 #Post Controller 
  class Post < ApplicationController
    ...
    def show
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end
    ...
  end
```

Comment: It still says undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass for line 40 which is:

<% if current_user.id == @post.user_id %>

Comment: what do you get if you just do `<%= current_user.id %> <%= @post.user_id %>`

Comment: Do I not need the if statemnet though?

Comment: The current_user and post.user_id have to be the same.

Comment: undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass

is at

<% if current_user.id == @post.user_id %>

it doesn't know what user_id is

Comment: Even though i have this line of code working in the same file:

<td><%= post.user_id%></td>

Comment: I am thinking that you are not login, and you don't have a `current_user` object

Comment: I do have a user logged in! I appreciate your help so much I am desperate.

Comment: I just made a change `if current_user && current_user.id == @post.user_id`

Comment: I still get the same error it doesn't know what user_id is.

Comment: in your db / migrations do you have a `user_id` make sure that there is not a typo

Comment: Look in the console if you can see `Post.last.user_id`

Comment: I do have that yes! user_id has worked every other time I used it in this application

Comment: Where and how do I view the console?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130634/discussion-between-thor-odinson-and-jill1993).

Comment: can you see other elements of the `@post` ?

Comment: you can find the console by doing `rails c` in the terminal